# Webdriver new DefaultWait generic

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I want to have method like this in my `IDriver` class

```
this.driver.WaitUntil(x => LoginForm.Displayed, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

this.Driver is a IDriver field
```

This one does not wait for element displayed:

```
public void WaitUntil(Func<IDriver, bool> condition, TimeSpan timeout)
{
    var wait = new DefaultWait<IWebDriver>(this.Driver)
    {
        Timeout = timeout
    };

    bool result = wait.Until(condition);

    if (!result)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

`this.Driver` is a `IWebDriver` field in my `Driver` class

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool WaitForWebElementToBeNotPresent(IWebElement module)
{
    var result = true;
    try
    {
        _driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        if (module.Displayed)
        {
            result = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```